# Cannot concurrently consume from ActiveMQ embedded broker

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm looking for a way to publish 10 messages to an ActiveMQ embedded broker and, at the same VM, concurrently consume they using JMS API.

The code below has some kind of race, because sometimes it consumes 2, 4, 8 messages in parallel, and hangs until timeout at the `latch.await` call.

```
public final class ActiveMQJMSParallelTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActiveMQJMSParallelTest.class);
    private static final int numberOfMessages = 10;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
        props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
        props.setProperty("queue.parallelQueue", "parallelQueue");
        final Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(props);
        final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        final Destination destination = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup("parallelQueue");
        final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMessages; i++) {
                final TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                message.setText("This is message " + (i + 1));
                producer.send(message);
                logger.info("Produced message: {}", message);
            }
            session.commit();
        } finally {
            if (session != null)
                session.close();
        }

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numberOfMessages);
        final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfMessages);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMessages; i++) {
            pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    try {
                        final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                        connection.start();
                        final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                        final Queue destination = session.createQueue("parallelQueue");
                        final MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
                        final Message received = consumer.receive();
                        logger.info("Consuming message: {}", received);
                        latch.countDown();
                        latch.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                        logger.info("Consumed message: {}", received);
                        session.close();
                        connection.close();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        jndiContext.close();
    }
}
```

Can somebody conjure working code for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that each consumer gets a chance to grab one message at a time then you should use a prefetch value of zero so that the broker does not try and dispatch up to the prefetch limit for the first consumer and so on as they arrive.

Have a look at how prefetch works on the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) page.

Comment: Thank you for answering here, Timothy.

Comment: The following line change is necessary for this example to work: `"vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0"`